# Not able to enable 'Configuration Translation' module gives error

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am trying to enable MULTILINGUAL -> Configuration Translation.

It gives below error.

> Error: Call to a member function getPath() on null in Drupal\config_translation\ConfigNamesMapper->getOverviewRoute() (line 247 of /var/www/project/docroot/core/modules/config_translation/src/ConfigNamesMapper.php) #0 /var/www/project/docroot/core/modules/config_translation/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php(39): Drupal\config_translation\ConfigNamesMapper->getOverviewRoute() #1 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteSubscriberBase.php(37): Drupal\config_translation\Routing\RouteSubscriber->alterRoutes(Object(Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection)) #2 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase->onAlterRoutes(Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent), 'routing.route_a...', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) #3 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(111): call_user_func(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent), 'routing.route_a...', Object(Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) #4 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(184): Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('routing.route_a...', Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuildEvent)) #5 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(83): Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() #6 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(322): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild() #7 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(83): Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, true) #8 /var/www/project/docroot/core/modules/system/src/Form/ModulesListForm.php(458): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array) #9 [internal function]: Drupal\system\Form\ModulesListForm->submitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #10 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormSubmitter.php(111): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #11 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormSubmitter.php(51): Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #12 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(589): Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #13 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(318): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('system_modules', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #14 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/FormController.php(93): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('system_modules', Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #15 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), Object(Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch)) #16 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #17 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(582): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() #18 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure)) #19 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) #20 /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() #21 /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1) #22 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #23 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #24 /var/www/project/docroot/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(99): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #25 /var/www/project/docroot/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(78): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #26 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #27 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #28 /var/www/project/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #29 /var/www/project/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(669): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true) #30 /var/www/project/docroot/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #31 {main}.

I am not sure what exactly cause of this. Anyone faced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be caused by a module which doesn't provide a base path for a config entity, see for example:

https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_layouts/issues/3002255
https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy/issues/2703717
https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_entity_embed/issues/3014901
https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/2919676
https://www.drupal.org/project/salesforce/issues/3040022